# Do golfing languages support rational number arithmetic?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I proposed this code golf on sandbox:

> ## Integer Logarithm
>
> Take \$a \in ℤ_{>1}\$ and \$b \in ℤ_+\$ as inputs. Write a function \$f\$ that:
>
> $$
> f(a,b) =
> \left\{
>     \begin{array}{ll}
>         \text{Just} \space \log_ab & \quad \text{if} \space \log_ab \in ℚ \\
>         \text{Nothing} & \quad \text{otherwise}
>     \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> ### Rules
>
> - Types and formats of the inputs doesn't matter, but they must be able to represent at least 2 bits. For example, in C++, `int`, `unsigned`, `std::vector<bool>`, or even `std::string` containing ASCII digits are acceptable.
> - Type and format of the output doesn't matter either, but the fraction must be irreducible. In C++, `std::optional<std::pair<int,unsigned>>` is an example.
> - **You must not use floating-point numbers because of their errors.**
> - if \$a\$ and \$b\$ aren't in the sets as specified above, the challenge falls in *don't care* situation.
> - \$f\$ may be curried or uncurried.
> - As this is a code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins.

But to think about it, I doubt that golfing languages natively support rational number arithmetic. Unlike [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194339/89459), it actively requires arithmetics on rational numbers, in sake of, for example, Newton's method.

Do major golfing languages such as 05AB1E, Jelly, APL, and Charcoal natively support rational number arithmetic?

Comment: Can't this be done using just integer types?

Comment: @xnor Do you mean you want \$\log_a{b} \in \mathbb{Z}\$?

Comment: No, I mean the solver can work with just integers by finding `p,q` so that `a^q = b^p`, and outputting `p/q`. Actually, even the ratio of their respective counts of prime factors in their factorizations should suffice.

Comment: @xnor Aha! So it is possible with just integer types. Thanks. I will post it in few hours if there is no objections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## APL

… is not a golfing language.

That said, some APL implementations, like NARS2000, feature rational arithmetic. Others, like Dyalog APL, have a library that provides this functionality. Additionally, some APL derivatives, like J, do too.